# Backbone sometimes load sometimes not

Tags: json, backbone.js

I have a Backbone app where I load external Json.
Sometimes I see the image inside the json(url) sometimes not, like the fetch doesn't finish in time.
Json that doesn't load sometimes are amenities (that contains url to image) and image (that contains url to image)

This is my app simplified:

```
HotelModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            // because initialize is called after parse
            _.defaults(this, {
                amenities: new AmenityCollection(),
                image: new ImageCollection()
            });
        },
        parse: function(response) {
            if (_.has(response, "image")) {
                this.image = new ImageCollection(response.image, {
                    parse: true
                });
                delete response.image;
            }
            if (_.has(response, "amenities")) {
                this.amenities = new AmenityCollection(response.amenities, {
                    parse: true
                });
                delete response.amenities;
            }

            return response;
        },
        toJSON: function() {
            var json = _.clone(this.attributes);
            json.rooms = this.rooms.toJSON();
            return json;
        },
        addAmenity: function(amenities, options) {
            return this.amenities.add(amenities, options);
        },
        addRoom: function(rooms, options) {
            return this.rooms.add(rooms, options);
        },
        addImage: function(image, options) {
            return this.image.add(image, options);
        }
    });

    AmenityModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    ImageModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    HotelCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: HotelModel,
      }
    });

    AmenityCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: AmenityModel,
        getAmenitiesByHotelId: function(hotelId) {
            return this.where({
                hotelId: hotelId
            });
        }
    });

    ImageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ImageModel,
        getImagesByHotelId: function(hotelId) {
            return this.where({
                hotelId: hotelId
            });
        }
    });

    var CombinationView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
        template: _.template($("#hotel-list-template").html()),

        initialize: function(){ 
            this.hotels = new HotelCollection([],{ 
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>json_upload/hotels_details_<?php echo($this->session->userdata("id")); ?>.json' 
            }); 

            this.amenities = new AmenityCollection([], { 
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>json_upload/hotels_details_amenities_<?php echo($this->session->userdata("id")); ?>.json' 
            });

            this.image = new ImageCollection([], { 
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>json_upload/hotels_details_images_<?php echo($this->session->userdata("id")); ?>.json' 
            });


            this.hotels.on("sync", this.hotelsLoaded, this); 
            this.amenities.on("sync", this.amenitiesLoaded, this); 
            this.image.on("sync", this.imagesLoaded, this);

            this.hotels.fetch(); 
        }, 
        render: function(){ 
            this.$el.html('Loading...'); 
            return this; 
        }, 
        hotelsLoaded: function(){ 
            this.image.fetch();
            this.amenities.fetch(); 
        }, 
        amenitiesLoaded: function(){ 
            this.hotels.each(function(hotel) { 
                hotel.addAmenity(this.amenities.getAmenitiesByHotelId(hotel.id)); 
            }, this); 
        },
        imagesLoaded: function(){ 
            this.hotels.each(function(hotel) { 
                hotel.addImage(this.image.getImagesByHotelId(hotel.id)); 
            }, this); 
        },
        displayCombinations: function(){ 
            $(this.el).html(this.template({hotels: this.hotels.models}));
        } 
    });
```

Can someone explain me why sometimes i see the image in the template and sometimes not?

This is a little piece of template with some console.log

```
    <% _.each(hotels, function(hotel1, index_hotel) { %>
            <%
            console.log('hotel:'); 
            console.log(hotel1);

            console.log('amenities');
            console.log(hotel1.amenities.models); %>
            <% _.each(hotel1.amenities.models, function(am) { 
//NOT ENTER HERE SOMETIMES!!!
                            if(am.attributes.image!=''){
                                var src = '<?php echo(base_url()); ?>/img/backend/ameneties/' + am.attributes.image;
                            }
                            else{
                                var src = '<?php echo(base_url()); ?>/img/backend/ameneties/NO_IMG.jpg';
                            }
                        %>
           <% }
    }
    %>
```

The first log of hotel show the full hotel and inside it I see amenities.models with all, but in the log of ameneties is empoty like is t was loaded before.

Comment: Do you see the xhr calls completed in your console?

Comment: Yes I see the right response @Ingro

Comment: Good and the syncs events are fired? In this situation i suggest you to call console.log in each step to find out where the correct event chain broke.

Comment: if I put a console.log inside the function of sync of ameneties the log is visible in the console but I can't see the image.. not normal.. @Ingro

Comment: Update question with the template and some more info @Ingro

Comment: Now I have  solved with a setTimeout of 500 when I print the template. But I don't like this waY!. @Ingro

Comment: When you call the function that print the template?

Comment: yes inside render @Ingro

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33685/discussion-between-ingro-and-alessandro-minoccheri)